# Only one value passing to another php page

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to set values using a textfield and then passing these values through an url to another page. I thought my method was working but it does not and I realize my mistake here.

I have a textfield like so:

```
  Voornaam: <h3 class="title1">Kevin</h3>
  <input type="text" id="myTextField1" />
  <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change1()"/><br/>
```

And this can trigger the change1() function:

```
function change1(){
   var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField1').value;
   if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
       alert('Write Some real Text please.');
   return;
   }
  document.getElementById("myLink").href="convert.php?var1=" + myNewTitle +"&var2=";
   var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title1');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles,title => {
    title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
   });
}
```

As you can see it sets var1 but leaves var2 empty, var 2 should be coming from another textfield which is linked to change2() which is the entire same function except for the href line, that line is changed to this:

```
   document.getElementById("myLink").href="convert.php?var1=&var2=" + myNewTitle;
```

I understand that when I've called both functions, and change2() the last.. var 1 is ofcourse empty again. However I wish to have them both set, var1 and var2.

Could anybody perhaps tweak my code a little so that it actually keeps both of them set and not empty the other one?

Also I really do prefer seperate functions for my textfields.

Comment: Why would you prefer mass duplication of code by having separate functions? If, as you say, they are identical but for the field they target, that suggests you should be harmonising this into a single function. It would also solve the current problem you face.

Comment: It's currently required but you are always allowed to suggest a piece of code that can change this and uses one function instead.

Comment: "It's currently required" -- no it's not required, just because you're doing it right now. There are plenty of techniques to re-use code, you're just not using any of them.

Comment: This is for a school project, and the one that gave me the task told me I best keep it the way it is now. In the future I'm gonna have to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (only uses one change button):

```js
document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function change() {
  function isInvalid(input) {
    return input.value.length == 0;
  }

  var titles = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="title"]')];
  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="myTextField"]')];
  var anchor = document.querySelector('#myLink');
  
  if (inputs.some(isInvalid)) {
    alert('Write some real text please.');
    
    anchor.href = 'convert.php';
  } else {
    var querystring = inputs.map((input, index) => `var${index + 1}=${titles[index].textContent = input.value}`);
    
    anchor.href = `convert.php?${querystring.join('&')}`;
  }
});
```

```css
a:after {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
Voornaam:
<h3 class="title1">Kevin</h3>
<input type="text" id="myTextField1" />
<br/><br/>
Achternaam:
<h3 class="title2">Bosman</h3>
<input type="text" id="myTextField2" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Change" />
<br/><br/>
<a id="myLink" href="convert.php"></a>
```

Comment: Seems like a great solution, Does exactly what I wish for it to do except from being able to change each value seperately. They don't all require to be changed sometimes. I'll be trying this out shortly when I have a bit more time. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, when pressing the change button.. it doesn't do anything. I've also pasted the code into a seperate file.. with just your code. Still no luck. It also tells me cannot read property of addEventListener .. null.

Comment: Never mind, I feel quite stupid. The function wasn't in the correct place. The change button works now, however I get Write some real text please so I'll see to fix that.

Comment: Works splendid now!